# Prove that a sequence decreases monotonically

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

let: $$C_n = \left|\left(a-\frac{(n-b)^n}{n^n}\right)\right|$$
I want to find for which values $C_n$ is decreases monotonically in other words: when $C_{n+1} < C_n$?

I started writing it but it was so hard since sometimes $n$ is even sometimes it's not and sometimes it's negative and others it's positive.

Comment: any help, I am stuck

Comment: Answer: $a>e^{-b}$. Can you prove this?

Comment: what you said is not true, a can be smaller than this value